# How to get value from JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hmmm.. I have this json values:

```
var form = {
lat: event.row['lat'].value,
lon: event.row['lon'].value,
}

Android.openForm( $.toJSON(form) );
```

How do I get the value from lat and long?

```
openForm: function( json ){
    alert(json[lat]);
    //$('#lat').val(json.lat);
}
```

Comment: You just need quotes around `lat`, at the moment it is being parsed as a variable and it should be a string: `alert(json['lat']);`

Comment: alert(json); shows me all the values in the json. but I don't know how to access the individual values like lat and lon

Comment: I assume that the `form` variable is not available from the `openForm` function, and you required the JSON serialization to transfer the data **since that's what JSON is for**. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you have the openForm receive the object directly instead of its json serialization?

```
openForm(form){
    var json = $.toJSON(form);
    alert(form.lat);
}
```

Comment: but i passed the form to the function and named it json.. :|

Comment: `$.toJON` Who's Jon? ;) Or is that the new Java Object Notation? ;)

Answer (score 2):

If the results of `form` is to be this

```
var form = {
lat: "somevalue",
lon: "somevalue"
};
```

You would access the data in the variable `form` by the dot properties.

`form.lat` and `form.lon`

[Simple Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/jLXnA/)

Comment: How do you know `form` is available from the `openForm` function?

Comment: if(form == undefined) return; ??

Comment: Your answer might provide a valid alternative (assuming that `form` is available in the scope where the function is called) but seriously misuses the term JSON.

Comment: There is little context to how or what is forming the variable. But given the example, it looks like the OP is building a js variable and passing it to a method.

Comment: `var form = {...}; form.lat;` isn't an example of JSON, so it isn't correct to say *"You would access the JSON data in the variable..."*.

Comment: I agree. Just for context, do you have an issue calling `var form = {...};` a json object? http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: @ScruffyTheJanitor: Yes. That's a JavaScript object literal, which is part of an evaluated JavaScript environment. JSON is text that could potentially be eval'd into JavaScript (or some other language), but until then, it isn't the same. There are examples of JSON data that would not evaluate as valid JavaScript code. The link between the two is that JSON *notation* is *based on* the object literal *notation* found in JS.

Comment: From my experience, it seems that a Javascript object literal formatted in such a way, is commonly called a js json object. I understand what you are saying though, the OP is not providing a string, but what looks like to me as a js object.

Comment: Well, I'd agree that the object can successfully be serialized into JSON, but it could also be serialized into a querystring, but I wouldn't call it a js querystring object.

Comment: *"the OP is not providing a string"* Except that `$.toJSON` takes the object and creates JSON serialized data from it. So if that data is being transferred to another environment, it would need to be parsed before its properties could be accessed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5593/discussion-between-scruffy-the-janitor-and-rightsaidfred)

Comment: Funny that your answer was down-voted after you removed references to JSON. That would at least remove any controversy. +1 to offset.

Answer (score 1):

`$.toJSON(form)` converts your object to a string, I think you want to pass the object so just drop it:

`Android.openForm(form);`

Answer (score 0):

Didn't realize that my team mate was using a plugin...
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

I should have asked him first.. @_@ 
Sorry neh

```
var thing = {plugin: 'jquery-json', version: 2.3};

var encoded = $.toJSON( thing );
// '{"plugin":"jquery-json","version":2.3}'
var name = $.evalJSON( encoded ).plugin;
// "jquery-json"
var version = $.evalJSON(encoded).version;
// 2.3
```

Comment: That's what I figured was happening, but you shouldn't use `$.evalJSON` every time you want to access a property. You should process it once, and store the result. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8390637/376743) for an example. I'll update it to use the method in your plugin.

Comment: @황현정 - You can update your original question and add information there. This is great info but doesn't really fit as *answer*.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
openForm: function( json ){

    var lat = json.lat;//or json["lat"]
    var lon = json.lon;//or json["lon"]

}
```

By the way variable `form` is already a well formed json you don't have to convert it to json in order to use it.

Comment: If `json` contains (as the name suggests) a JSON string, you can't do that: you need to parse it first. And `form` is not well formed JSON; it's not even a string.

Comment: Looking at OP's question it looks like a well formed json.

Comment: That's because you are possibly confusing [JSON](http://www.json.org/) with [JavaScript objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Comment: JSON is a `JavaScript` object itself. The point is we don't have to parse this object in order to access its properties.

Comment: ShankarSangoli: JSON is text, that is able to be parsed into a JavaScript object if you wish. Until then it is (assuming a JavaScript environment) a String.

Answer (score -1):

If `$.toJSON` is a method like `JSON.stringify`, then you've serialized the data into JSON text, so it's values are no longer available via properties.

You'd need to parse it first.

```
openForm: function( json ){

     // UPDATED to use the JSON plugin you've loaded
    var parsed = $.evalJSON( json ); 

    alert( parsed[lat] );
}
```

*I assume that the original `form` variable is not accessible from where you're trying to retrieve the value, otherwise you probably wouldn't serialize it in the first place.*

If the original `form` data is in the same execution environment, and could be accessed directly from your function, you should do that instead of serializing.

---

### *What is JSON, and why do we use it?*

For those who don't understand what JSON is meant for, it is a text based serialization format used to transfer data between environments where data can not naturally be shared.

The serialization is simply a standardized format that gets "stringified" from the native data structures of one environment, and then parsed into the native data structures of a different environment.

I assume `toJSON` is the "stringify" function, and the `openForm` is the separate environment into which the JSON data has been transferred.

If these assumptions are correct, the JSON needs to be parsed into the new environment before its values can be easily accessed.

Comment: Who has downvoted (and why) the first correct answer so far? Not enough jQuery?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I wish I could upvote you more than once.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: I wish you could too since I just received another downvote. Ugh!

Comment: Ah, I see some fourteen-year-old is going around down voting my correct answers.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: Okay, I've had enough of that. If you'd like me to prove I didn't downvote *any* of your answers, I'll add a downvote if you'd like, then take it off. Or give you a screenshot of two unhighlighted arrows. Whatever you'd like. You know what they say about assumptions, and it sure is applying right now.

Comment: @minitech: I didn't mention you. What, are you scouring my comments now because I've taken issue with your inappropriate behavior on another question? This is bordering on harassment.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: I could say the same to you. What are you, looking on my profile to find all *my* comments? Finally, you're insinuating, you know that very well (hey, DataSO query, I'm the only 14-year-old currently on the site! And you posted this comment but an hour ago! Go figure) and **that's bordering on harassment**.

Comment: @minitech: Dude, you're sending me notifications with every one of your comments. You would have received no notifications for this. And I received two invalid down votes (this being one of them) about 2 hours ago, and commented as soon as I saw the votes. And while I did see that you were 14, I intentionally didn't reference your user name because I would have no way to prove that it was you. Instead I used it as a general reference to immature behavior. You should have no issue with that since you weren't the down voter.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: I do, since you incorrectly assumed I was the downvoter. And so I notified you to tell you I'm not. And I'll just not bother any more.

Comment: @RightSaidFred - how bizarre - the best answer has the lowest score.  I'll +1 this in 6 hours when you're not capped anymore.  BTW - do you know what the draw of this plugin is?  How is $.toJSON and $.evalJSON any better than the native JSON.stringify and jQuery's native $.parseJSON?

Comment: @RightSaidFred - also, if you're the "victim" of down-vote fraud, report it to team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: @AdamRackis: I don't know why that is being used. Could be an old plugin to bring compatibility before `jQuery.parseJSON` was introduced in `1.4.1`. And to be honest, I know that I'm usually pretty blunt with people, and so I expect some down votes. When I get them, I'm just sure to call the voter out for an explanation. Sometimes my answer is genuinely wrong, but often times someone didn't like what I had to say elsewhere. I guess I'd rather be right, and down voted, than wrong and up voted. :)

Comment: @Right I don't know, based on some of the personalities I've seen around here, `For those who don't understand what JSON is meant for` is pretty mild.  The rest of your answer is just plain, simple, and answers the question.  As it should be.

Comment: @Right - LOL - speaking of being wrong an upvoted, there's a horribly wrong answer on here that was deleted; it managed to score a +1.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Thanks, but I've got to admit, I have my moments, though I do stop short of name calling or ridicule. That was part of the issue I had with minitech. He left what was IMO a deriding comment for another user that really had no relevance to the issue at hand. And yes, I've seen some incredibly bad answers get lots of upvotes. Usually because the answer is short.